# ByteBuffer and ByteArrayInputStream same underlying byte[]

Tags: java, bytearrayinputstream

Is it "safe" to have a `ByteBuffer` and a `ByteArrayInputStream` share an underlying `byte []` as long they only read from it? If I read/get from one and then the other, since each has their own internal marks/counters etc., is there a possibility of a conflict?

Answer (score 2):

Judging from the source of [`ByteBuffer.wrap`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/nio/ByteBuffer.java#ByteBuffer.wrap%28byte%5B%5D%29) and [`ByteArrayInputStream`'s constructor](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.java#ByteArrayInputStream.%3Cinit%3E%28byte%5B%5D%29), it looks like both classes would store the array that you pass them without making a copy. It also appears that neither class would modify the array, making it safe to share the same `byte[]` array across multiple instances of `ByteBuffer` and `ByteArrayInputStream`.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe, with one caveat.  There must be a *happens before* chain to ensure that the threads using the shared `byte[]` can see the last write to the `byte[]` prior to it becoming "effectively immutable".

In simple terms, the threads need to synchronize when setting up the sharing,

Comment: OP didn't ask about multi-threading, but perhaps they should have.

Comment: Well ... to my mind ... "safe" includes all kinds of safety, including thread safety.  As I read it, they are asking about thread safety, among other things.

Comment: The part of the code I'm using this in is sequential, but thanks for the heads up re: thread safety. I originally meant only in terms of somehow modifying the underlying `byte []`